# Different Code Analysis results on the same rule set

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, code-analysis, azure-devops

When running the exact same rule set on our local machines and on the build server on the same code base (TFS on Visual Studio Online), we get different results.

**Code Analysis output from local:**

```
Running Code Analysis...
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop\FxCopCmd.exe  
/outputCulture:1033 
/ruleSet:"=C:\Workspaces\ProjectName\CodeAnalysis\CodeAnalysisRuleSet.ruleset" 
/rulesetdirectory:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\\Rule Sets" 
/rule:"-C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop\\Rules" 
/searchgac 
/ignoreinvalidtargets 
/forceoutput 
/successfile 
/ignoregeneratedcode 
/saveMessagesToReport:Active 
/timeout:120
```

**Code Analysis output from build server:**

```
Running Code Analysis...
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop\FxCopCmd.exe  
/outputCulture:1033 
/ruleSet:"=C:\a\Sources\ProjectName\Trunk\SharedResources\..\..\CodeAnalysis\CodeAnalysisRuleSet.ruleset" 
/rulesetdirectory:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\\Rule Sets" 
/rule:"-C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop\\Rules" 
/searchgac 
/ignoreinvalidtargets 
/forceoutput 
/successfile 
/ignoregeneratedcode 
/saveMessagesToReport:Active 
/timeout:120 
MSBUILD : error : CA1034 : Microsoft.Design : Do not nest type 'SpatialFunctions.RelativeStopType'. Alternatively, change its accessibility so that it is not externally visible.
  Code Analysis Complete -- 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

The build server picks up an issue which was missed on the local analysis (CA1034).

The only difference that I can see is that TFS is using MS Visual Studio 11 tools (whereas we are developing with VS 12.0).  I can't imagine why this should make a difference.

We are using Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Question: you say you're using Visual Studio Online (VSO) to store the source code, are you also using their build servers? Or have you configured a local build server?

Comment: I am also using their build server.  Sorry for not being explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your build server is using the FxCop binaries from Visual Studio 2012, not those of 2013. Each time a new version of Visual Studio is released there have been some updates to the rules to fix bugs and there have been a few rules that got added. There's also a difference in [certain code generation scenario's](http://blog.jessehouwing.nl/2012/11/net-framework-sdk-45-changes-visual.html) between .NET SDK versions.

Given this knowledge, I am not surprised that there are different findings from the different versions of the tools. How to fix it you might ask? Install Visual Studio 2013 on the build server and make sure your "Run MSBuild for Projects" activity in team build points to the correct toolsdirectory (the MsBuild one that ships with Visual Studio 2013).

Or: Make sure you're using TFS 2013 and Team Build 2013, which should figure this out by itself if both versions of Visual Studio are installed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  We are using the build services available on Visual Studio Online, and hence cannot upgrade.  Having to install VS 2012 on all of the developer machines is also not feasible. Is there any other way to solve this?

Comment: I'd expect VS 2013 to be installed on the build servers of VSO... I'm wondering whether you're using an older build process template, but that's hard for me to debug in a chat window.

Comment: I looked into the process template and found the following Activity attribute:  `this:Process.BuildProcessVersion="11.0"`.  I will set this to 12.0.  Could there be any repercussions of this?

Comment: That it will try using the VS2013 on the server :). Seems exactly what you want it to do.

Comment: It didn't make a difference.  Nowhere else in this file is 11.0 or 12.0 specified :(

Comment: I fixed it by adding the following MSBUILD argument: `/p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0`.  Marking your answer as complete as your help ultimately lead me to the solution!

Answer (score 2):

The CA1034 rule has been changed in VS2013 to ignore nested enums.  If you don't want nested enums ignored, you would need to add a custom rule to detect them under VS2013.  If you don't mind ignoring them, then building under VS2013 on the build server would seem to be the easiest way to resolve the discrepancy.  (Regardless of how you decide to handle the discrepancy, building under the same VS version on developer machines and the build server would be very much recommended.)

Comment: This would explain why CA1034 was the only difference. Thanks